# Hint on a measure theory question

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ be a measure space, and define 
$\mu^\bullet: \mathcal{A} \to [0, +\infty]$ by

$$
\mu^\bullet (A) = 
\sup
\left\{
\mu(B) : B \subseteq A, 
B \in \mathcal{A}, \mu(B) < + \infty 
\right\}
$$
I'm trying to show that $\mu^\bullet$ is countably additive. One thing is clear: if $A_n$ are disjoint sets in $\mathcal{A}$, then if $B \subseteq \cup_n A_n$, and $B_n = B \cap A_n$, then 
$$
\mu(B) = \sum_n \mu(B_n) \leq \sum_n \mu^\bullet(A_n),
$$
thus $\mu^\bullet(\cup_n A_n) \leq \sum_n \mu^\bullet(A_n)$. This is the easy direction (I think).

Could I get a small hint on the reverse inequality? (I don't want the solution...)

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
1. If $\mu^\bullet(A_n)=\infty$ for some $n$, show that $\mu^\bullet(\bigcup_n A_n)=\infty$.
2. If for all $n$, $\mu^\bullet(A_n)<\infty$, we can find $B_n\subseteq A_n$ such that $\mu(B_n)>\mu^\bullet(A_n)-\epsilon/2^n$. Let $B=\bigcup_n B_n\subseteq \bigcup_n A_n$.
3. If $\mu(B)=\infty$, try to use $\color{blue}B_N=\bigcup_{n=1}^N B_n$ instead, and show that $\mu^\bullet(\bigcup_n A_n)=\infty$.

Comment: I appreciate the help. The point is that for $\epsilon > 0$, there is some $B_n \subset A_n$, such that $\mu^\bullet(A_n) - \mu(B_n) < \epsilon 2^{-n}$, and thus there is a $B = \cup_n B_n \subset A$ such that $\sum_n \mu^\bullet(A_n) - \mu(B) < \epsilon$, and hence passing to the supremum, $\sum_n \mu^\bullet(A_n) - \mu^\bullet(\cup_n A_n)  < \epsilon$, giving the result. But how do you deal with the annoying infinite edge cases? (For example, if $\cup_n B_n$ has infinite $\mu$-measure)

Comment: @DrewBrady Use $B_N$ in Hint 3 (which is of finite measure and contained in $\bigcup_n A_n$) to show that $\mu^\bullet(\bigcup_n A_n)=\infty$.

Comment: Ah I see. So if $\mu(B) = +\infty$ and $C_N := \cup_{n=1}^N B_n$, then $\mu(C_N) \uparrow +\infty$. But on the other hand, $C_k \subset \cup_n A_n$ for all $k$, and thus $\mu^\bullet(\cup_n A_n) \geq \lim_k \mu(C_k) = +\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: fix $\epsilon>0$ and for each $n$ take $B_n$ with $\mu(B_n)+\epsilon/2^n>\mu(A_n)$, then try to use the fact that $\sum_n\epsilon/2^n=\epsilon$.